# Easily run out of memory when use Eclipse and Ant/Junit on my Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, osx-mavericks

Now that OSX Maverick works with memory different (so it seems and from what I've read), when I run Java as a separate JVM (Ant/JUnit/etc.), I often get OutOfMemory exceptions as it bases the max heap on memory available which is usually close to zero (because that's apparently how Maverick works?).  I know I can set the max heap space using the -Xmx argument for a run or external tool configuration in Eclipse, but that is a pain when I have several possible configurations that can be run.

I believe I would have to run in a separate JVM so my configurations don't get polluted with Eclipse classpath JARs and to a smaller extent, so the Eclipse JVM doesn't get polluted with configuration runs and all the class loading that goes on.

Is there a global setting to set the max heap available for all JVMs launched by Eclipse?  For Ant, I tried setting ANT_OPTS in my environement to "-Xm1024m", but that setting doesn't seem to take when running Ant through Eclipse.  If I run Ant from the command line directly, it does seem to work (or at least I didn't get an exception).  When running Ant in verbose+debug mode in Eclipse, I do see "Setting project property: env.ANT_OPTS -> -Xmx1024m" so I know the variable is set.

I ran Java VisualVM to get a better idea what is going on, this is what it has:

```
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.7.0_25, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
JVM Flags: <none>

Main class: org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner
```

[image]

Comment: Java server JVM sets the maximum heap to 1/4 of main memory, not the amount free. The Java client JVM, has a default of 64 MB no matter the memory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, if that is the case, then how is my JVM getting limited to 8MB when running 64-Bit Server VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running VisualVM made me realize Eclipse was still using 1.7.0_25 and not 1.7.0_45 which is the latest I have installed.  Once I updated Eclipse to use 1.7.0_45, I no longer have the issue as the VM does indeed use 1/4 of total memory.  Would be nice to know for sure, but it seems like build 25 had a bug or something.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure JVM arguments for an Eclipse Ant build in the `Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations` dialog in the `JRE` tab.

Note that the default is actually to run Ant in the same JVM as Eclipse (which makes some additional Eclipse tasks available).

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can change the default behavior to do this, but that is not the default (http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-antprefs.htm).  I'll have to try this out.  Turns out I have similar issues when running JUnit so my problem is bigger than Ant.

Comment: Actually, this will not work for JUnit at all, see my updated question, can't use the same JVM as Eclipse for JUnit, even if it is allowed, because of classpath issues.